# GitLab commit as other person

Tags: git, gitlab

I am working in someone's project but wanted to my own GitLab, so I tried this:

First I cloned the project:

```
git clone git@otherpersonsproject.git
```

Then I set the git to my own URL:

```
git remote set-url origin http://gitlab.mygitlab.com/something.git
```

And now I push the project in the empty directory.

```
git push

Username: usernamefrommyserver
Password: mypassword
```

Now in my own server I click on `Project` see that the uploader is `SomeoneElse` instead of myself. How did this happen? I need it to show my user and e-mail, since GitLab sends email automatically and they should go to myself.

Comment: What is the `hostname` and user? I had an issue where `ubuntu@localhost` was already allocated to another user on Bitbucket and because it was the tail of my ssh key, that was used to "identify" my user incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your local repository directory, run command

```
git config user.name "Your Full name"
git config user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

Then

```
git push
```

See result on sever.

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html

Answer (score 2):

Author information is stored for each commit, and is independent of who pushed it.
Since you took the repository from someone else it makes sense that they are marked as the author of those commits.

If you make new commits and push them to your server they should be authored by you.

If alters seem reconfigured then you may want to check gitlabs's options

---

It is possible to change the author on every single one of the previous commits but I would advise against it since it will involve modifying the whole repository, which may take a while, obfuscate the real author, and make it difficult to for anyone else who has cloned your repo to pull updates.

We are now entering **dangerous territory**, the following involves rewriting history.

The following `git filter-branch` command should work, on the latest version of git.

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
    GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="<your name>"
    GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=<your email>
    GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="<your name>"
    GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=<your email>
' -- --all
```

After you will have to force re-push each branch `git push --all --force`.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the `.git` folder from the root directory of the project before using `git remote set-url origin http://gitlab.mygitlab.com/something.git`.

It should erase everything stored and give you a clean project

Comment: Why would deleting the `.git` dir solve anything on the remote repository?

Comment: Because it contains configuration data from the previous project that you don't need and don't want